# Recursion Friends Confusion

Tags: java, recursion

My program takes data from an outside text file and puts this data into a list of names as well as numbers. The numbers represent the friendships (i.e. if at index 2 there is a 1 for a person. This means this person is friends with the person of names[1].) From here it is supposed to take a name and display who the person's direct friends are and then display the indirect friends (Indirect friends are the friends of a person's friends.) My current problem is that my program displays the indirect but I am unsure of how to send it into my base if statement to print the direct friend. If anyone could shed some light that would be greatly appreciated.

Th data in the names array(String): ["Smith","Adams","Steward","Stein","Mankell","Yorst"]

The data in the numbers array(String):
["000010","001001","01000","000010","100100","010000"]

I called the method on smith (directFriends("Smith", names,numbers,1)

I Am getting this for out put:

Indirect Friends of Smith:

Mankell is Friends with Smith

Mankell is friends with Stein

My desired output is:

Smith is friends with Mankell

Indirect Friends of Smith:

Mankell is Friends with Smith

Mankell is friends with Stein

```
public class AllFriends {



public static void directFriends(String name,String[]names,String[]numbers, int num){
ArrayList<String> indirect = new ArrayList<String>();

if (num==0){
    for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        if(names[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            for(int j=0;j<numbers[i].length();j++){
                if(numbers[i].charAt(j)=='1'){
                    System.out.println(name+" is friends with "+names[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else
    //Go through names array
    for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        //To see if name entered is the same as a name from the list
        if(names[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            //For each character in the individual number String
            for(int j=0;j<numbers[i].length();j++){
                //Check if it's a 1(Friends)
                if(numbers[i].charAt(j)=='1'){
                    //Then add this friend to the group of people needed to be friend searched 
                    indirect.add(names[j]);
                    //If 
                    if(j==numbers[i].lastIndexOf("1") ) {

                        for(int f=0;f<indirect.size();f++){
                            System.out.println("Indirect Friends of "+name+":");
                            num--;
                            directFriends(indirect.get(f),names,numbers,num);

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: "include the desired behavior": that means you need to provide the data being used and the actual output you expect.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thank you for clarifying that. Sorry for the misinterpretation. I have just updated the question with the following information

Comment: How can Smith (or anyone else) be friends with Stein, directly or otherwise, when Stein isn't in the list of names?

Comment: @ScottHunter that was actually mistake on my part I just added him in. But I also got it to work thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got it to work for anyone who was curious here is my solution All I had to do was re order and add a line in my final for loop in the else statement:

```
public class AllFriends {



public static void directFriends(String name,String[]names,String[]numbers, int num){
ArrayList<String> indirect = new ArrayList<String>();

if (num==0){
    for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        if(names[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            for(int j=0;j<numbers[i].length();j++){
                if(numbers[i].charAt(j)=='1'){
                    System.out.println(name+" is friends with "+names[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else
    //Go through names array
    for (int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
        //To see if name entered is the same as a name from the list
        if(names[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
            //For each character in the individual number String
            for(int j=0;j<numbers[i].length();j++){
                //Check if it's a 1(Friends)
                if(numbers[i].charAt(j)=='1'){
                    //Then add this friend to the group of people needed to be friend searched 
                    indirect.add(names[j]);//New stuff
                    //If 
                    if(j==numbers[i].lastIndexOf("1") ) {

                        for(int f=0;f<indirect.size();f++){
                            num--;
                            **directFriends(name,names,numbers,num);
                            System.out.println("Indirect Friends of "+name+":");
                            directFriends(indirect.get(f),names,numbers,num);**

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```